# How to auto extend the height of frame in java swing

Tags: java, swing, jframe

i am created small frame with 500,500 size, in my frame i added panel also, i have added a label and text box dynamically, i added 10 labels in my panel it's showing correctly but i will add another 5 labels and text box continuation of above added labels means after of 5 labels and text box's are hiding, so how to ***I EXTENDS A HEIGHT OF FRAME AUTOMATICALLY***

Comment: Consider putting the labels in a panel that is in a `JScrollPane` instead, as seen in the labels of [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556).

Answer (score 3):

Calling the [`.pack()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29) method should do the trick:

> public void pack()
>
> Causes this Window to be sized to fit the preferred size and layouts
>   of its subcomponents. The resulting width and height of the window are
>   automatically enlarged if either of dimensions is less than the
>   minimum size as specified by the previous call to the setMinimumSize
>   method. If the window and/or its owner are not displayable yet, both
>   of them are made displayable before calculating the preferred size.
>   The Window is validated after its size is being calculated.

Comment: Note that this will change the width as well.

Comment: @aioobe: If the components fit length wise, shouldn't that remain unchanged?

Comment: Nope. `pack` shrinks the width if it can.

Answer (score 2):

there are a few important rulles and required knowledge how concrete LayoutManager works with min, max and PreferredSize came from its childs

1. I'd strongly suggest to add `(re)validate()` and `repaint()` for already visible `Container`
2. use `JScrollPane` as first `JComponent` added to the `JFrame` / `JDialog` / `JWindow` and with to determine maximum size for `JFrame` (best could be from display resolution), don't use `pack()` in the case that maximum size is exceeded, otherwise containers bounds could be out of the screens

code example, have to add rules in point 2nd.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class AddComponentsAtRuntime {

    private JFrame f;
    private Container panel;
    private JCheckBox checkValidate, checkReValidate, checkRepaint, checkPack;

    public AddComponentsAtRuntime() {
        JButton b = new JButton();
        b.setBackground(Color.red);
        b.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 2));
        b.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 10));
        panel = new Container();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        panel.add(b);
        f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(panel, "Center");
        f.add(getCheckBoxPanel(), "South");
        f.setLocation(200, 200);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel getCheckBoxPanel() {
        checkValidate = new JCheckBox("validate");
        checkValidate.setSelected(false);
        checkReValidate = new JCheckBox("revalidate");
        checkReValidate.setSelected(false);
        checkRepaint = new JCheckBox("repaint");
        checkRepaint.setSelected(false);
        checkPack = new JCheckBox("pack");
        checkPack.setSelected(false);
        JButton addComp = new JButton("Add New One");
        addComp.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JButton b = new JButton();
                b.setBackground(Color.red);
                b.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 2));
                b.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 10));
                panel.add(b);
                makeChange();
                System.out.println(" Components Count after Adds :" + panel.getComponentCount());
            }
        });
        JButton removeComp = new JButton("Remove One");
        removeComp.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int count = panel.getComponentCount();
                if (count > 0) {
                    panel.remove(0);
                }
                makeChange();
                System.out.println(" Components Count after Removes :" + panel.getComponentCount());
            }
        });
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.add(checkValidate);
        panel2.add(checkReValidate);
        panel2.add(checkRepaint);
        panel2.add(checkPack);
        panel2.add(addComp);
        panel2.add(removeComp);
        return panel2;
    }

    private void makeChange() {
        if (checkValidate.isSelected()) {
            panel.validate();
        }
        if (checkReValidate.isSelected()) {
            panel.revalidate();
        }
        if (checkRepaint.isSelected()) {
            panel.repaint();
        }
        if (checkPack.isSelected()) {
            f.pack();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                AddComponentsAtRuntime makingChanges = new AddComponentsAtRuntime();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no boolean which you can set to true in order to make the frame grow automatically.

You probably want to do `getPreferredSize()` of the content panel each time you add something, and do `frame.setSize(...)` to accommodate for the new components.

Here's a demo

```
public class FrameTestBase {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        final JFrame t = new JFrame();

        t.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(-1, 1));

        t.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Add label") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                t.getContentPane().add(new JLabel("hello"));

                // Auto-adjust height.
                Dimension dim = t.getContentPane().getPreferredSize();
                dim.width = 500;
                t.setSize(dim);
            }
        }));

        t.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        t.setSize(500, 500);
        t.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```